# SQL Server : count of values stored in a multiple values holding parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, sql-server-2012

I have a parameter which holds an alternating amount of values inside. In some cases it has only one value, which is empty and I need to identify these situations.

Here's a simplified example of what I've tried:

```
SELECT Id, Name, City
FROM Example
HAVING ((City IN @Cities) OR @Cities = '')
```

Where `@Cities` is a parameter holding multiple values (city names). The example crashes if `@Cities` has multiple values. `IS NULL` and `IS EMPTY` also result in as a crash

I'm looking for a query that returns the whole database when the parameter has no values. The project a SSRS report and I'm using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: The form `IN @VARIABLE` is only valid in dynamic SQL (a concatenated string)

Comment: you want your query to do all this or you can add some code ? if yes, in wich language ?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you should have a set for this rather then varchar variable. 
But if you insist, you can do what you want like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, City
FROM Example
WHERE @Cities IS NULL OR @Cities = '' OR @Cities LIKE '%' + City + '%'
```